I am learning about non-well-founded sets and I wanted to know what books everyone recommends.
I am currently studying "A Course in Model Theory" by Bruno Poizat and I am doing research with altering the set of set theory's axioms. I want to further learn about the effect of the axiom of regularity and non-well-founded sets. I have already had someone recommend Peter Aczel's "Non-Well-Founded Sets" and I was curious what books on non-well-founded set theory anyone would recommend.

Does Poizat actually cover the axioms of set theory in A Course in Model Theory? I promise you that the choice of whether to include regularity among the axioms of set theory has no impact whatsoever on the theorems of model theory covered in Poizat's book.

@AlexKruckman I'm sorry, I worded this poorly and edited the question to better reflect what I am trying to say. I am studying model theory as part of my own research at school and I wanted book recommendations for non-well-founded sets.

Another book on non-well-founded set theory is Vicious Circles by Barwise and Moss. It also includes material on applications of non-well-founded sets in computer science and philosophy.

Some entry-points:

Start with Lawrence S. Moss, ‘Non-wellfounded set theory’, The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, tinyurl.com/sep-zfa.

Keith Devlin, The Joy of Sets (Springer, 2nd edn. 1993), Ch. 7. The last chapter of Devlin’s book, added in the second edition, starts with a very lucid introduction, and develops some of the theory.

Peter Aczel, Non-well-founded Sets (CSLI Lecture Notes 1988). This is, as no doubt others have mentioned, a very readable short classic book. It is available at tinyurl.com/aczel.

Luca Incurvati, ‘The graph conception of set’ Journal of Philosophical Logic (2014) pp. 181-208, or his Conceptions of Set and the Foundations of Mathematics (CUP, 2020), Ch. 7, very illuminatingly explores the motivation for such set theories.



Fantastic. Thank you.
